# Vertically align fontawesome icon with flexbox

Tags: css, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

I wan't to align vertically my icons inside a list item. I've tried some approaches, but I can't figure it out how to align the icons properly to the center. This is the most visible in example bellow with arrow icon, near the close icon. Any ideas?

```css
li {
  display: flex;
}

.fa {
  flex-grow: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
        <span class="title">Item 1</span>
        <span class="fa fa-sort-down"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
        <span class="title">Item with long title</span>
        <span class="fa fa-sort-down"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: the properties of alignment should be added to parent element (the flex container)

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is not a flexbox issue. It's a font-awesome issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, **you can't**...some of the glyphs aren't **centered** in their bounding font-boxes.

You can see this if you put a border around the icon.

**This is not correctable with flexbox.**

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.fa {
  flex-grow: 0;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
    <span class="title">Item 1</span>
    <span class="fa fa-sort-down"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
    <span class="title">Item with long title</span>
    <span class="fa fa-sort-down"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you have noted yourself

> "There is a `fa-caret-down` icon, which is properly centered."

and this seems to be the appropriate alternative.